# About the sufficient conditions for an upperbound for an integral ratio.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, integral-inequality

Let f and g be functions, I am interested in finding (if there is any) the sufficient conditions on f and g such that we can satisfy an inequality of this type:

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx} \leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$$

What I am interested in reality is to show that one limi its zero, but I want an upper bound that converges to 0 instead. I assumed that my functions f and g satisfies such conditions and I could get the limit. If anyone have experience with this kind of inequality, any help  or insight will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you rather look for _sufficient_ conditions, right?

Comment: @amsmath I modified the question. Thanks.